# Android : Network Main exception in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I did this code to change the `tabs` name from `HTML` but i got this error :

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork
```

I know you can't do `networks` operations on the `main` `thread` but here i use `runOnUiThread` so it should be this error.

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://terry.gonguet.com/cal/?g=tp11").get();
                                Elements days = doc.select("div.day");

                                for (Element day : days)
                                {
                                    String jour = day.getElementsByClass("dayDate").first().html();

                                    mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new MainFragment().newInstance(1), jour);



                                }
                            }catch (IOException ex){}
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            thread.start();
```

Comment: ui thread is the main thread

Comment: The main thread is the UI thread, so you should not be doing network operations in there.

Comment: By using `runOnUiThread` you _are_ running it on the main thread. That's what `runOnUiThread` does. Try using AsyncTask instead.

Comment: @JonasCz yeah i know but i cant chaneg the name of tabs using asynctask because i cant acces the adapter from an asynctask class right ?

Comment: You _can_ access the Adapter from AsyncTask, that's what it's meant to be used  for. The easiest way would be to have your asynctask as an inner class of your activity (ie. not as a separate file in your project), and it should work.

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace.

Comment: ... and while doing what @JonasCz says, I'd suggest to declare the parent variables accessed in the inner class, specially those related to the UI, as package, so you don't leak contexts

Comment: You can add your network operation code in asyncTask. That is the right way to do network/long running operations that does not need user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

`I know you can't do networks operations on the main thread`

You clearly are doing network operation in the main thread since `runOnUiThread` will run on the main thread and you are calling `Jsoup.connect` which is a network connection.

You need to either create an `AsyncTask` which is preferable than a `Thread`; unless you are doing a long running task.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run network operations on the UI thread because your interface will freeze until the finish of network operatin, you can use AsyncTask for this, it is the perfect solution for this kind of operations. With AsyncTask you can run a network operation and update the UI after (and even during) the network operation. For example:

```
 new AsyncTask<String, String, Elements>(){

        @Override
        protected Elements doInBackground(String... params) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://terry.gonguet.com/cal/?g=tp11").get();
            Elements days = doc.select("div.day");

            return days;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Elements days) {

            for (Element day : days) {
                String jour = day.getElementsByClass("dayDate").first().html();

                mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new MainFragment().newInstance(1), jour);
            }
            }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only add the fragments inside the UI thread but not the request so this should work:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        try
        {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://terry.gonguet.com/cal/?g=tp11").get();
            Elements days = doc.select("div.day");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    for (Element day : days)
                    {
                        String jour = day.getElementsByClass("dayDate").first().html();

                        mSectionsPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new MainFragment().newInstance(1), jour);



                    }

                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex){}          
    }
};
thread.start();
```